# jQuery UI Sortable Doesn't Work After Adding to Collection (BackboneJS)

Tags: jquery, jquery-ui, backbone.js

I essentially am attempting to create a Trello list that shows cards inside of it. Inside this list is also a card form to add a card. I can use jQuery's Sortable UI just fine in dragging/sorting the cards inside the list--until I add a card, at which point I then can no longer drag and drop the cards.

The HTML associated with this view (in a `.jst.ejs` file:

```
<div class="cards">
    <div id="sortable-cards" class="card-list-area"></div>
  <div class="add-card-area">
    <a>Add a card...</a>
    <form class="hidden">
        <textarea></textarea>
        <button class="card-add-submit btn btn-success">Add</button>
        <span class="glyphicon glyphicon-remove"></span>
    </form>
  </div>
</div>

<script>
  $(function() {
    $( "#sortable-cards" ).sortable({
        update: function (event, ui) {  
           var index = ui.item.index();
           ui.item.trigger('dropCard', [ui.item.data('id'), index]);
           var data = $(this).sortable('serialize');
           $.ajax({
                data: data+"&authenticity_token="+AUTH_TOKEN,
                type: 'PATCH',
                url: '/api/cards/update_order'
            });     
       }
    });
    $( "#sortable-cards" ).disableSelection();
  });
</script>
```

BackboneJS view:

```
  //this.model refers to the "list"
  initialize: function (options) {
    this.board = options.board;
    this.listenTo(this.model, 'sync', this.render);
    this.listenTo(this.model.cards(), 'sync change add remove sort', this.renderCards);
  },
  render: function () {
    $(this.el).attr('id', 'listID_' + this.model.get('id')); 
    var content = this.template({list: this.model});
    this.$el.html(content);
    this.renderCards();
    return this;
  },

  renderCards: function () {
    this.model.cards().each(function (card) {
      this.$el.find('.card-list-area').prepend("<article id=cardID_"+card.get('id')+" class=group>"+card.escape('title')+"<span class=remove-card hidden glyphicon glyphicon-remove data-sort="+card.get('id')+"></span> </article>"); 
    }.bind(this))
  },
```

I think the way I'm implementing `renderCards()` is causing the issue. Before, I rendered the cards inside of the `div.card-list-area`, but I decided to move it out of the HTML document and into the Backbone view for other reasons. How could I solve my problem by keeping `renderCards()` where it currently is? And what exactly is happening that's causing this issue? Thanks!!

Comment: I'm wondering what `this.model.cards()` returns. could you create a fiddle for this?

Comment: Where are you initializing the jQueryUI sortable? I second the request for a fiddle.

Comment: It turns out that if I replace `render` with `renderCards()` in the listener to `this.model.cards()` (as shown in the view's `initialize` method above), then the ability to drag and drop works. This is weirding me out.

Comment: So the `<div class="cards">` is the view's `el` and you're binding the jQuery-UI stuff somewhere outside the view?

Comment: @muistooshort, yes to your first point, and I am binding the jQuery-UI in the HTML (it's a `.jst.ejs` file) associated with the Backbone view (I edited it into the code above).

Comment: jQuery's `html(x)` function erases everything (the HTML elements, events, ...) before it adds the new HTML. You need to move the jQuery-UI stuff inside your view so that you can bind it at the right times. I'd recommend moving everything inside your view (i.e. don't bind the view to an existing `el`, let the view create it on its own) too, you'll have fewer problems that way. Your views should be as self-contained as possible.

Comment: Just to clarify about the sequence of things that happen when `render` is called: is all the JavaScript inside the `script` tag run after `this.template` is called? In my mind, I'm not exactly sure when that HTML `.jst.ejs` file is "run"...